# What is the metre of "High Waving Heather" by Emily Bronte?

Tags: poetry, meter, emily-bronte

I really like ["High Waving Heather"](https://press.uchicago.edu/Misc/Chicago/284468bronte.html) by E. Bronte:

> High waving heather 'neath stormy blasts bending,
> Midnight and moonlight and bright shining stars,
> Darkness and glory rejoicingly blending,
> Earth rising to heaven and heaven descending,
> Man's spirit away from its drear dungeon sending,
> Bursting the fetters and breaking the bars.
>
> All down the mountain sides wild forests lending
> One mighty voice to the life-giving wind,
> Rivers their banks in their jubilee rending,
> Fast through the valleys a reckless course wending,
> Wider and deeper their waters extending,
> Leaving a desolate desert behind.
>
> Shining and lowering and swelling and dying,
> Changing forever from midnight to noon;
> Roaring like thunder, like soft music sighing,
> Shadows on shadows advancing and flying,
> Lighning-bright flashes the deep gloom defying,
> Coming as swiftly and fading as soon.

I like the rhythm of it, the rhyme, but I am a bit rusty since last time I "studied" poetry was in high school.
Is it iambic? What is the metre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's dactylic tetrameter. That means that there are four feet per line, and each foot is DUM dah dah.

> HIGH waving HEATHer 'neath STORmy blasts BENDing,

The feet at the ends of the lines are shorter, a few lines have extra syllables at the beginning, and a few feet are irregular, but this doesn't change the basic meter.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's catalectic dactylic tetrameter. Most falling meter in English (trochaic or dactylic) is catalectic because feminine rhymes sound comical in English.

Comment: @verbose: It's not necessarily true that feminine rhymes sound comical in English: consider [If, by Kipling](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46473/if---), and [Reveille, by Housman](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/reveille-2/),  two very well-known and well-liked poems. Poems with badly done feminine rhymes sound comical (and there are many more of these than good ones).